# How does the size get calculated when using GetPreferredSize()?

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, label

I'm using label to display the message. I have calculated the size of the label by using `GetPreferredSize()` method. This method works fine when I didn't do any manipulation in sizing the label. But when, I reduce the width of the label, the text gets clipped. However, if I include a newline(`\n`) at the end of the text to be displayed, the text which gets clipped in previous case is displayed in the next line.

Here is what I tried.

```
label1.Text = "Are you sure you wish to cancel? \n You will permanently discard any information you have entered!";
label1.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Calibri"), 15); 
Size textSize = label1.GetPreferredSize(Size.Empty); //Works fine.
label1.Size = textSize;


textSize.Width -= 25;
label1.Size = textSize;// Text is clipped.

label1.Text = "Are you sure you wish to cancel? \n You will permanently discard any information you have entered! \n "; //Works fine again!
```

Refer to the image,
[Label Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yclYO.png)

If the method calculates the size of the label based on the contents, why does the content clipped in case2 and works good in case3? How does the width and height is related to?  Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Thanks,

Sindhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Size sz = new Size(this.Width, Int32.MaxValue);
            sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, this.Font, sz, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
            this.Height = sz.Height;
```

where "this " is your control.

Answer (score 0):

How big was text size before decreasing it by 25? Maybe it's just not enough space and cut off - try with a different number. And ... you certainly wanted to subtract and not assign?

Comment: please refer to the attached image, in which, the word 'entered' disappears, which again is displayed in case3. Width to be decreased is based on some calculation which cannot be modified. Suggest any idea on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the "Anchor" setting to only anchor to the left or the right